# Kendo scheduler: move event between schedulers

Tags: events, kendo-ui, move, scheduler

I have multiple kendo schedulers and would like to move events between schedulers, but it seems not possible.

(I know how to drop an item onto a scheduler from an external control, but that does not help because I cannot make the event "leave" the scheduler.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed by default Kendo Scheduler does not support dragging events out of the timeslot area. One possible way to achieve similar behavior is by using custom functions for the mousemove and mouseup events and simulate the drag and drop as for example it is done in this

[dojo page](http://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/OlIKE).